# How do I implement paging to "Controller/ with read/write actions and views, using Entity Framework" wizard-generated code?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4

This is ASP.MVC 3 controller code generated by the "Controller/ with read/write actions and views, using Entity Framework" Wizard packaged with the EF 4.1 tooling. It works great in demos when you have 10-20 records, but when you pull data from a DbContext with 10,000+ records, it obviously slows way down and produces an unusably long page.

So, how would you modify Index() to implement paging in the *db.Courses.ToList()*?

```
// wizard generated MVC Controller code
namespace Scheduler.Controllers
{ 
  public class CourseController : Controller
  {
    private CourseEntities db = new CourseEntities();

    //
    // GET: /Course/

    public ViewResult Index()
    {
        // returns over 10,000 courses in the list
        return View(db.Courses.ToList());
    }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems a little Linq to Entities is in order.

Here's my modified Index() controller:

```
public ViewResult Index(int page = 0)
{
    int pageSize = 10;
    var courses = db.Courses.OrderBy(c => c.Id).Skip(page * pageSize).Take(pageSize);
    return View(courses);
}
```

Then construct links in the View that append the page parameter to the url like this:

/Course?page=2

Comment: Hmm... to get 1 based page numbers requires a bit more math: set the initial page to 1, and subtract 1 after that.

Comment: ...While it works, is there an HTML Helper that works without sending 10,000 records to the View?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the PagedList NuGet package.  See this tutorial:
http://www.asp.net/entity-framework/tutorials/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Comment: That looks very promising! I'll take a look at it. Thanks! :-)